# google-cloud-sdk "gcloud projects list" is no longer showing projects list

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

The "gcloud projects list" command is no longer is showing my projects.  Instead, it returns "Listed 0 items." .  This is the case for google-cloud-sdk that I run locally on my machine, as well as the "cloud shell".  If I log into console.cloud.google.com , I can see that I do in fact have active projects.

If I run "gcloud init", it sometimes shows my projects, othertimes, it says I have no projects.

It was working fine yesterday.  Any ideas?

Comment: COMMENT REMOVED.  Thought it was working now...but its not.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly a guess.

This command will list the currently active `gcloud` user:

```sh
ACCOUNT=$(\
  gcloud auth list \
  --format="yaml" --filter="status=ACTIVE" \
  --format="value(account)"\
) && echo ${ACCOUNT}
```

Is this the same account that you're using in the browser? I suspect not.

Since `${ACCOUNT}` is the default, the following is a more explicit way of ensuring that you're listing the projects for which this `${ACCOUNT}` has access:

```sh
echo ${ACCOUNT} && gcloud projects list --account=${ACCOUNT}
```

If the accounts match and `gcloud` is not working, the issue must be that there's an issue with your `gcloud` installation.

One improbable issue could be that Google does not (correctly) canonicalize Gmail (all Google?) Accounts. If the Gmail account that is referenced by your Google Cloud Platform projects includes periods (`.`), you must use these when attempting to access these projects.

As far as Gmail is concerned `your.name@gmail.com` == `yourname@gmail.com`. Periods are not significant. You can email `y.o.u.r.n.a.m.e@gmail.com` and this will work. However, as far as GCP is concerned, periods **are** significant and you must use the same address.

Comment: It resolved itself.  I submitted a ticket to google, and they very rapidly had someone working it.  No answer as to WHY, but it works now.  I also noticed my console.cloud.google.com website was randomly showing/not showing my projects, so I suspect there was some sort of server-side issues they were working through

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but is `echo ${ACCOUNT)` written that way because it's a string literal ?

Comment: The command displays the value of the environment variable `ACCOUNT`

Comment: If you don't want to run the full Bash script, running `gcloud auth list` directly will show all credentialed accounts for the machine, and the current active account. This is often enough to determine if your active account is correct.